# How do I cure "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree"?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, h2

I'm using Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, JPA 2.0, JUnit 4.8.1, and the H2 in-memory database.  I have this JPA query ...

```
@Override
public List<Organization> findByOrgTypesCountryAndState(final List<OrganizationType> organizationTypes,
                                                        final String countryId,
                                                        final String stateId)
{
    final CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<Organization> criteria = builder.createQuery(Organization.class);
    final Root<Organization> org = criteria.from(Organization.class);
    criteria.select(org);
    criteria.where(builder.and(
                       org.get("organizationType").in(organizationTypes),
                       builder.equal(org.get("state").get("id"), stateId),
                       builder.equal(org.get("country").get("id"), countryId)));
    return entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
}
```

When the java.util.List, organizationTypes, is empty, the above query dies with the below exception.  Is there another type of predicate I should use to account for this case?

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [select generatedAlias0 from org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.Organization as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.organizationType in () ) and ( generatedAlias0.state.id=:param0 ) and ( generatedAlias0.country.id=:param1 )]" type="java.lang.IllegalArgumentException">java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [select generatedAlias0 from org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.Organization as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.organizationType in () ) and ( generatedAlias0.state.id=:param0 ) and ( generatedAlias0.country.id=:param1 )]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1347)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1288)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:506)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler.compile(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:220)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:623)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.createQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.mainco.subco.organization.repo.OrganizationDaoImpl.findByOrgTypesCountryAndState(OrganizationDaoImpl.java:   232)
        at org.mainco.subco.organization.repo.OrganizationDaoTest.testFindByOTCSEmptyOrgTypeList(OrganizationDaoTest.java:82)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
```